# groups of projects in intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins, set, project

For now, at least since IntelliJ Idea 14+, ide remembers the last set of opened projects. 
Could we control it comfortably and have switchable sets (groups) of projects?
This is another way of opening projects, not like Modules.
My hope is some plugin already do the functionality, but which one?

Comment: If you are requesting a feature for a product, the better place to submit it would be [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA). Otherwise please make your question clear. Here is the [related feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-141558) to show groups in the recent projects list. Is that what you need?

Comment: We usually ask for a feature when we shure, there is no such a feature. 
My question was whether some thing is already present or not.
I was almost shure there is already some plugin to do it, but probably with some exotic name out of my search skills. If i would decide to request a feature, i would probably find right place to do so. But i'm glad u are able to put down here the link above i haven't seen and agree in that the idea is a good candidate for a feature request. And I've fixed my question a bit.

Comment: @WebComer, if my answer below solves the question, could you please accept it? thanks

Answer (score 21):

As of 2017-08, IntelliJ Idea 2017.2.1 can group projects.

To use the feature, in the project selection window, right-click on the project name:

[image: how to work with groups]

I've created a group called 'kata', that contains 'camel-snake-pascal-kebab', 'strikeitrich', 'gildedrose'.

With the groups closed:

[image: projects grouped]

with an open group:

[image: projects grouped with a project open]

Comment: Is there an option to re-arrange project groups?

Comment: this function is also usable in the File -> Open Recent drop down menu?

Comment: @ad3luc Same question. If I have 40 projects in the recents list, still hard to find the one I want without groups displayed. Or is there a shortcut to open the "Manage Projects..." modal (Recent Projects window)? My current "work-around" is to press CTRL+SHIFT+A to open the actions search window, type "Manage P" and open the window from there quickly.

Comment: @Snackoverflow I'm starting to use this https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/ . I think that this is the best way to navigate quick between multiple project. Ok, you lose the group concept but the search is working really well and fast. You can also configure specific version of Intellij for specific project. Have you already tried it?