# How to automagically load a set of Java Projects in separate IDE instances when opening only one project?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

**Disclaimer first:**

- I know how to combine several Maven Projects to a multi-module project and open all of them in one IDE instance
- I know how to open multiple projects manually in separate windows (= multiple IDE instances)
- I know how to set the option for not being asked about the opening in separate windows in Intellij every single time
- I know about the "reopen projects on startup" option

Having said that, I desperately need to know if there is a feature in the Intellij IDE to automatically open multiple projects in separate IDE instances when loading one (of the wanted) projects.

I came cross this question because I had a session where I had 6 related micro service projects open in 6 instances of the Intellij IDE. Then a Windows 10 security updated did not bother that I was working and booted my machine... bummer...

After the Windows desktop came back again, all of the Intellij instances opened up again automagically.
As this happened alongside with the restore of other applications which had been opened before the reboot, I believe that it was done by the OS, quite surprising.

The question is: how can I achieve to always have such a convenient behavior when loading my 6 service projects or any other combination of related projects?

Does anybody have a good idea or can hint me to something obvious I have missed so far?
I have searched the web thoroughly but I found only answers to the topics mentioned in the "disclaimer" at the beginning.

Comment: Curently it's not possible. Feel free to create feature request on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Comment: thank you for the information, so I can stop seaching for the trick ;-)
I definitely consider creating a feature request.

Comment: funny thing is: I just experienced, if I have several projects open and Intellij does an update, it restarts with exactly the projects open again I had been working on before...so it might be only a small stept for a developer, but a giant leap for developer-kind.

Comment: please refer to my latest answer, where I link to a solution to do the trick. It probably is exactly what the IDE does in case of an update/restart when you have several projects opened. By creating groups on the IntelliJ welcome screen you are able to use that feature for yourself. There is no need for a feature request anymore ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently came across a much better way of doing exactly what I need and this is available for many years without me noticing it, shame on me...

It was already posted here on stackoverflow and with the correct search terms it was  very easy to find.
Please refer to this answer, because it still works for IntelliJ 2021+ exactly like described there:

[groups of projects in intellij idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43558618/groups-of-projects-in-intellij-idea)

Thanks to [alvaro g](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1181094/alvaro-g) for the great description of the procedure.

The answer is: use the IntelliJ Welcome screen!